# Microsoft Azure SQL Database and VM connection

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm looking at spinning up an Azure VM to run some apps I've written that will need to connect to a SQL server; hopefully Azure SQL. However, I've noticed that it seems my connection to the DB is through the internet. Since my workload consists of many, many writes and reads with very little work each, the latency has a dramatic effect on performance. If I create a SQL VM(IaaS), I can connect the two through a more direct virtual network. Is there a way to do the same with Azure SQL(SaaS)?

Comment: This should be on ServerFault. That said: What leads you to believe your traffic is routed through the internet? Because, if you choose the same region for your VM and your database service (or database VM), the traffic is within the region itself.

Comment: I suppose that's a poor assumption. What I'm looking at is the completion time of my task. Writing about 70,000 records takes about 1 minute when running locally with a local SQL server. When I run on an Azure VM with a SQL VM, both on the same virtual network, it takes 5 minutes, and when running on that same Azure VM with an  Azure SQL DB, it takes 15 minutes. The SQL DB perf monitor shows very little utilization throughout this. Less than half the allotted 'DTUs' and only 4% CPU and 1% I/O. They are both in the same region..

Comment: This could be related to the VM sizes you chose, the data disks you're using with your SQL VM, or the tier you're using with SQL Database. You've shared none of that.

Comment: Well, I was trying to use this site to ask a specific question. 'Can an Azure SQL Database join a virtual network'. I'm thinking then that the answer is no. That said, I now realize who you are. If I pay for a service plan, could you help me with this more directly?

Comment: Moving the SQL Database from the Standard pricing tier to the Premium tier brought performance in line with the SQL VM. Guess that's it. Thanks.